# Regular vs long run SVAR estimates

Tags: vector-autoregression

What is the difference between regular and long run SVAR model?

I don't understand how the matrices with restriction are different. Is there a different number of restrictions for the long run case?

Comment: Could you give a small example, i.e. a concrete model with its equations and restrictions you mention? Could you also give a reference if you are following a textbook, lecture notes, an article or the like?

Comment: Have you made any progress yet?